# zsh always show Python virtual env

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, zsh

I currently have this script to show my GitHub branch and virtual env:

```bash
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
autoload -Uz vcs_info
precmd() { vcs_info }
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '(%b)'
MYPS1=''
MYPS1+='%F{green}'
MYPS1+='${${(%):-%n}:0:1}'
MYPS1+='@'
MYPS1+='${${(%):-%m}:(-4)}' # Get last 4 chars of var machine name
MYPS1+=':'
MYPS1+='%F{yellow}'
MYPS1+='%1~' # Show only the name of the working directory or ~ if it is the home directory
MYPS1+='%F{magenta}'
MYPS1+='${vcs_info_msg_0_}' # Show git branch if any
MYPS1+='%f'
MYPS1+='%# '
PS1=$MYPS1
```

Sometimes I need to update my `.zshrc` so I run:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

The problem is, whenever I reload my shell, I cannot see my Python virtual environment anymore even though it's still active.

```
# After activating virtual env
(my-ve-3.7.13) u@m1:repo-name(github-branch)%
# After reloading my zsh
u@m1:repo-name(github-branch)%
```

I use `pyenv` and `virtualenvs`.

How can I keep the virtual env name in my prompt?

Comment: Check for  a variable named `VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT` and add its value to your prompt if present.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do anything else to your prompt while the virtual environment is active, `deactivate` will simply replace the prompt with the value when the venv was created, rather than just removing the name of the venv from whatever prompt you defined in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @chepner's comment, I figured it out:

- Use `env` to see the list of all env vars. `pyenv` uses `PYENV_VERSION`.
- Add it to the prompt, use `()` to have the same look as `pyenv` does.

```
...
MYPS1=''
MYPS1+='($PYENV_VERSION) '
MYPS1+='%F{green}'
...
```